# How should I design MS Access 2010 tables for road construction projects?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

New to database design and admittedly over my head. Trying to create a small database that will allow me to find state highway construction project information along any given road. Relationships include:
One contract number to one project; One county to many projects; One road to many projects; One road to many counties and one county to many roads; One manager to many projects; One contractor to many projects; One contact list (phone, email) to one manager; One date each (bid, start, complete) to many projects.

Would be a small database, maybe 500 records total. There are only 6 counties. Right now I've broken roads down into 6 separate "roads by county" tables so while the route number may be the same in different counties each record will be unique because it's in a separate county table. Is this OK or is it better to keep one roads table and assign county values there? I created other tables listing the counties, contracts, contractors, managers, dates and project description. Just don't know what to do with them.

My purpose is to be able to search, mostly by road number and keyword, to find what projects are on what road at any given time. I'd also like to update this info via forms. The data will change frequently and it's just a little too unruly for a spreadsheet. I simply can't wrap my head around how to setup and relate the tables and individual records. Any thoughts would be phenomenally appreciated.

Comment: _"Is this OK or is it better to keep one roads table and assign county values there?"_ Most definitely have it all in one table!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine a database with a simple structure. 
The relations many-to-many normally should and can be avoided. 
Access doesn't have a direct implementation of this relations. You need to create a cross table between the two main tables.

Anyway I created a database for projects more complex than this so I tried to accomplish your request.

The "core" table is tblProjects that refers for details to other tables. 
Since projects are related to roads, I use road as the main item and a road can have a list of counties. If you want to know how many projects are in a county it can be simply done with a query looking for all the roads that have that County_ID.

If you want to look up for project for one road, simply find the road_ID (e.g. using a combo-box to select it) and you can filter (query) the tblProjects by Road_ID.

---

tblManagers

- ***IDManager**
- LastName
- FirstName
- eMail
- Phone
- Mobile

tblContractors

- ***IDContractor**
- ContractorName
- Reference

tblCounties

- ***IDCounty**
- CountyName
- **Road_ID**

tblRoads

- ***IDRoad**
- RoadNum
- RoadName

tblProjects

- ***IDProject**
- ContractNum
- ProjectName
- StartDate
- EndDate
- BidDate
- **Contractor_ID**
- **Road_ID**
- **Manager_ID**

The fields with * are the Key Fields. They are in relations with the _ID corresponding fields (check referential integrity and cascade deletion when you create the relation).
Let me know